# Changing cursor to custom cursor image as a resource

Tags: c#, wpf, resources, cursor

I've been trying to get my cursor to be a custom cursor from a .cur file located in a folder in my project as a `Resource`. Here's my solution layout:

- Solution

  - WPF Application
  - WPF Class Library

    - SampleControl.xaml (this is hosted in the WPF Application in the solution)
    - Images

      - test_cursor.cur

test_cur.cur's build action is set to `Resource`. In my class library is a `UserControl` at the top level which is what I want to change the cursor for. Here's the relative code:

```
public partial class SampleControl: UserControl
{
    InitializeComponent();
    StreamResourceInfo streamResource = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("test_cursor.cur", UriKind.Relative));
    Cursor = new Cursor(streamResource.Stream);
}
```

I've tried a few different variations of the `Uri` but I always get an error `Cannot locate resource 'test_cursor.cur'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working doing the following:

```
Uri uri = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/SampleClassLibrary;Component/Images/test_cursor.cur");
StreamResourceInfo streamResource = Application.GetResourceStream(uri);
```

`SampleClassLibrary` is the name of the class library project under the solution.

I had to make the `Uri` the way it was because the .cur file is a `Resource` under a class library and is being hosted in a different project under the same solution

Answer (score 1):

The file path is wrong.

```
 StreamResourceInfo streamResource = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("Images\\test_cursor.cur", UriKind.Relative));
Cursor = new Cursor(streamResource.Stream);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not working either. I get the same `Cannot locate resource` error.